# Adding multiple mailboxes by adding a single email address in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft, microsoft-outlook-365, system-administration

Before I begin , I want to apologize for asking such a childish question.

I saw yesterday user that had 4 mailboxes in his outlook. Whereas I saw only 1 account and 1 .pst file attached to outlook. So, my question is that is there a way to add multiple mailboxes just by adding one email address to outlook.
For e.g. I have added abc@xyz.com, but it should automatically install def@xyz.com, ghi@xyz.com and jkl@xyz.com as soon as I install abc@xyz.com to my outlook.

Is this something I have to do on the M365 admin portal?

Please assist.

Comment: Do above reply help to you? And how is your issue going?

Answer (score 0):

**In outlook side,** firstly, you should add the abc@xyz.com account then add def@xyz.com, ghi@xyz.com and jkl@xyz.com one by one via 'Add Account' button manually.[image] Once you done this, restart outlook, then choose the profile you have configured just now, you can see theses three accounts appear in outlook at the same time. If you done it in this way, it is not a smart way, you always need to manually add these accounts manually in other PC when you want to login in abc@xyz.com account and wants def@xyz.com, ghi@xyz.com and jkl@xyz.com to be kept.

**If you are exchange administrator,** you could follow below guidance to make these def@xyz.com, ghi@xyz.com and jkl@xyz.com automapping to the primary account abc@xyz.com.

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity abc@xyz.com -User def@xyz.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $true

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity abc@xyz.com -User ghi@xyz.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $true

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity abc@xyz.com -User jkl@xyz.com -AccessRights FullAccess -AutoMapping $true
```

Full Access permision allows the delegate to open the mailbox, and view, add and remove the contents of the mailbox and the mailbox auto-mapping feature uses Autodiscover to automatically open the mailbox in the delegate's Outlook profile.

For more details: [Manage permissions for recipients](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019)